# Multiple outputs in keras Sequential models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As I am reading the [Keras Code for Sequential models](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py#L170) I see that it only allows for a single output for any defined layer within the `Sequential` model. I am aware how to do this using the functional API (`Model` class).

However, I don't see why the `Sequential` model is limited to layers with a single output. Is there a design limitation for enforcing such constraint?

Answer (score 10):

Not actually. Sequential model is here to make things simpler, when designing smaller and straight-forward Neural Networks. As noted [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/), they can be useful for most problems.

> The **Sequential API** allows you to create models layer-by-layer for most
>   problems. It is limited in that it does not allow you to create models
>   that share layers or have multiple inputs or outputs.

But if you need more complex design, with multiple input/output as well as models that share layers, you can use the **Functional API** to achieve your goal.