# Using different sample weights for each output in a multi-output Keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

My input array is `image_array`, containing data of 10000 images of size 512x512 with 4 channels. I.e. `image_array.shape = (10000, 512, 512, 4)`. Each of those images has an associated metric I want to train a CNN to predict for me. Hence `metric_array.shape = (10000)`. Since I do not want the network to be biased towards values of the metric which just occur more frequently, I have a weighting array, containing a weight for each value of the metric. Hence `weightArray.shape = (10000)`.

I am using Keras. This is my Sequential model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, use_bias=True, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(512,512,4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, use_bias=True, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, use_bias=True, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation=relu_max))
```

I want to use the mean squared error loss function and the stochastic gradient descent optimizer. I compile my model:

```py
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01))
```

I split my dataset into training and validation:

```py
X_train, X_validate, Y_train, Y_validate, W_train, W_validate \
= train_test_split(image_array, metric_array, weightArray, test_size=0.3)
```

And finally train the model:

```py
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size = 32, \
           validation_data=(X_validate,Y_validate), sample_weight=W_train)
```

All the above works. Now, what I would like to do is to use 2 metrics instead of one. I have a value of metric1 and a value of metric2 for each image. And each of the values of metric1 and of metric2 have an associated weight. Hence

```py
metric_array1.shape = metric_array2.shape = weightArray1.shape = weightArray2.shape = (10000)
```

My network would then have two output nodes, one for each metric.

I tried changing the last layer above to:

```py
model.add(Dense(2, activation=relu_max))
```

I then combined the metric and weight data into a metric_array and a weightArray of tuples, with shape (10000, 2).
This led me to finding out that a Sequential model is designed for a single output, and that hence I should use a Functional model instead.

I have read some of the documentation and it seems quite complicated. I tried using the model above (but with 2 nodes in the last layer) and then doing

```py
from keras.models import Model
new_model = Model(model)
```

But it did not like it when I tried to compile it, because Model does not have the option `.add`.

Is there a simple way of modifying what I already have to obtain my new purpose? I would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: if you change your model structure, the previous weights becomes unusable.

Comment: Sequential model should be fine with multiple outputs

Comment: @Frobot See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679643/multiple-outputs-in-keras-sequential-models/53679838#53679838).

Comment: @venkata-krishnan Are you referring to the weights of the model with a single output? I am not interested in keeping them. I would like to have a new model with two outputs, which I can train on the dataset with two metrics.

Comment: You have *one* output **layer** with *two* **neurons**, therefore the Sequential API would work fine. On the other hand if your model has multiple output/input **layers** (and not neurons), then you must use Functional API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up a misunderstanding:

If your model has **one** output/input **layer** then you can use Sequential API to construct your model, regardless of the **number of neurons** in the output and input layers. On the other hand, if your model has **multiple** output/input **layers**, then you must use Functional API to define your model (no matter how many neurons the input/output layers might have).

Now, you have stated that your model has two output values and for each output value you want to use a **different sample weighting**. To be able to do that, your model must have **two output layers**, and then you can set the `sample_weight` argument as a dictionary containing two weight arrays corresponding to two output layers.

To make it more clear, consider this dummy example:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models 
import numpy as np

inp = layers.Input(shape=(5,))
# assign names to output layers for more clarity
out1 = layers.Dense(1, name='out1')(inp)
out2 = layers.Dense(1, name='out2')(inp)

model = models.Model(inp, [out1, out2])
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='adam')

# create some dummy training data as well as sample weight
n_samples = 100
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, 5)
y1 = np.random.rand(n_samples,1)
y2 = np.random.rand(n_samples,1)

w1 = np.random.rand(n_samples,)
w2 = np.random.rand(n_samples,)

model.fit(X, [y1, y2], epochs=5, batch_size=16, sample_weight={'out1': w1, 'out2': w2})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very clear. Which is the easiest way to then add the rest of the layers I had to such model you describe?

Comment: @Luismi98 I am not sure I understand your question correctly: do you mean "how we can build a model using Functional API?"? If that's the case, then the documentation is to the rescue since [it has covered this topic extensively](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: Thank you so much. This should be mentioned in the TensorFlow documentation...